# How to pass Parameter values from text box in sudzc generated code?

Tags: objective-c

I am new in XCODE Environemnt. I am a DOT NET Developer.

I made a web service and for utilization i use sudzc.com.

http://213.42.18.36/its_ws/inventorytrackingsystem.asmx?op=Login

I want to authenticate user name and password.

i dont know how i can pass paramater values from textbox.

can any body help me out , your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the instructions in Documentation/index.html, you should be able to do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {

    // Create a SOAP object. You might want to create it elsewhere and keep it around.
    MyService *service = [MyService service];

    // Fire off the SOAP call.
    [service LogIn:self action:@selector(handleLogIn:) username:@"AzureDiamond" password:@"hunter2"];
}

- (void)handleLogIn:(id)result {
    // This will run when the SOAP request fails or succeeds.
}
```